# Ruby on rails rake db:reseed abort

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, mongoid

I've a problem Rolify. When I use the command rake db:reseed in the shell, to reset my database I have this error:

> undefined local variable or method `rolify' for Customer:Class

Here's my code in my model with Rolify:

```
class Customer
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps
  rolify
  embeds_one :contact
  has_many :orders

  devise :database_authenticatable, :recoverable, :registerable, :timeoutable, :validatable,
         :token_authenticatable, :confirmable

  attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :add_role

  field :first_name
  field :last_name
  field :password
  field :gender
  field :confirmed_at
  field :unconfirmed_email
  field :confirmation_url
  field :confirmation_token
  field :confirmation_sent_at
  field :email
  field :encrypted_password

  gender_regex = /^(Male|Female)$/

  validates :first_name, presence: true, :allow_blank => true
  validates :last_name, presence: true, :allow_blank => true
  validates :password, presence: true
  validates :gender, presence: true, :allow_blank => true,
                     format: { with: gender_regex }
end
```

If you know why, please help me :)

Comment: What is that `rolify` command? What does it do and where it came from?

Comment: It's for the roles keep up https://github.com/EppO/rolify

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `rolify` from your your `Customer` model.
You need to follow the instructions on https://github.com/EppO/rolify

You should include it in your `Gemfile` and not in your model:

```
gem "rolify"
```

In the resource models you want to apply roles, you must include:

```
resourcify
```

I think it was your mistake....

Comment: have you included the `gem "rolify"` in your `Gemfile` and called the cmd `bundle install`?

Comment: yes here's my gemfile:

gem 'mongoid', '~> 2.4'
gem 'bson_ext', '~> 1.6'
gem 'cancan'
gem 'rolify'
gem 'devise'

Answer (score 0):

It might be late to answer, but for the sake of others who might still be facing this kind of problem.

I fixed this by restarting my server after adding rolify and resourcify in models.